# How to make openssl successfully in windows?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, openssl

When I make **OpenSSL** in my *WIN10 (VS 2013)*, I got a problem like this:

[image]

I don't know why it failed and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you are building openssl 1.1. The build process is a little difference with previous release.

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0c/INSTALL

on Windows (only pick one of the targets for configuration):

```
$ perl Configure { VC-WIN32 | VC-WIN64A | VC-WIN64I | VC-CE }
$ nmake
$ nmake test
$ nmake install
```

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_0-stable/INSTALL.W32

```
Visual C++
----------

If you want to compile in the assembly language routines with Visual
C++, then you will need already mentioned Netwide Assembler binary,
nasmw.exe or nasm.exe, to be available on your %PATH%.

Firstly you should run Configure with platform VC-WIN32:

> perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=c:\some\openssl\dir

Where the prefix argument specifies where OpenSSL will be installed to.

Next you need to build the Makefiles and optionally the assembly
language files:

- If you don't want to use the assembly language files at all then run:

  > perl Configure VC-WIN32 no-asm --prefix=c:/some/openssl/dir
  > ms\do_ms
```

Comment: Thank,I successfully make openssl with the method in github  https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_0-stable/INSTALL.W32 ,Thandkyou verymuch

Comment: You're welcome. If you do think this answer helps you resolved your problem, you can accept this answer then others can skip answering this question and save their time.